# for comprehension with isinstance

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

`javaInterface` returns an `Object` or `null`.

Expectation: `Some(String)` or `None`.

How can i write it better than

```
for {
  o <- Option(javaInterface.getValue) if o.isInstanceOf[String] 
} 
yield o.asInstanceOf[String]
```

simple pattern match is not a solution for option monad

```
for {
  a <- Option(javaInterface.getValue)
  o <- Option(a.getValue) if o.isInstanceOf[String] 
}
yield o.asInstanceOf[String]
```

Comment: Related: open ticket: Allow pattern matching on type in for comprehensions: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-900

Answer (score 5):

You can use `collect` to match on type:

```
for { 
    o <- Option(javaInterface.getValue).collect({case s: String => s})
} yield o
```

Comment: I had never used collect on an `Option` for some reason. Has to be the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: You don't need `for` comprehension. Simply `Option(javaInterface.getValue).collect { case s: String => s }` would work

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to `collect`, consider `filter` for instance as follows,

```
Option(javaInterface.getValue).filter { case s: String => s }
```